# Buen dia con todos Tengo un problema con visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

al crear el form me debería mostrar todos los controladores o herramientas como input, label. Y otros, pero no se que paso pero no me los muestra, eh buscado soluciones al restaurar el visual estudió a versiones de fabrica pero nada. Muestro imagen[image: imagen del codigo]